# Dynamically setting values to an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I get this to work?

Trying to set an array of blocks containing block objects...

```js
var blocks = [];
var block  = {
  type: null,
  color: null
};

var dom_blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

for( var i= 0, ii = dom_blocks.length; i < ii; i++) {
  blocks[i] = Object.create(block);
  blocks[i].block = dom_blocks[i].dataset.type;        // this kills my object
  blocks[i].block.color = dom_blocks[i].dataset.color; // this ain't working
}

console.log(blocks);
```

```html
<div class="block" data-type="false" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="true"  data-color="green"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="true"  data-color="orange"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="false" data-color="fuchsia"></div>

<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

**Update**
What I'm trying to achieve is to iterate over the HTML `<div class="block">` and write it to Javascript Objects which I'll need to manipulate later.

The desired end would be an array `blocks[]` containing the data from each `block` in an object.

Comment: Any advice why downvote and close?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve)."* You've done the MCVE (I assume), but what's the problem statement? The goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
 blocks[i].block = dom_blocks[i].dataset.type;
```

relies on the browser supporting `dataset`, which [isn't universally supported yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset). On browsers that do, it will set `blocks[i].block` to a string (`"true"` or `"false"`). For older browsers, you can use `getAttribute`:

```
 blocks[i].block = dom_blocks[i].getAttribute("data-type");
```

(BTW, perhaps you meant `.type =` rather than `.block =`?)

This line:

```
blocks[i].block.color = dom_blocks[i].dataset.color;
```

doesn't do anything, because you're setting a property `color` on a primitive string. When you do that, the string is promoted to an object briefly, but then that object is thrown away and this becomes a no-op.

So if things are "blowing up" it sounds like you're using a browser that doesn't support `dataset`. Otherwise, you just need to do something else with `color`.

Finally, there's no point in using `block` as a prototype if you're just going to assign its only properties to instances anyway.

If you wanted to set `color` on `blocks[i]` instead of `blocks[i].block`, e.g.:

```
blocks[i].color = dom_blocks[i].dataset.color;
```

...it'll work (on browsers supporting `dataset`):

```js
var blocks = [];
var block  = {
    type: null,
    color: null
};

var dom_blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

for (var i= 0, ii = dom_blocks.length; i < ii; i++) {
    blocks[i] = Object.create(block);
    blocks[i].block = dom_blocks[i].dataset.type;
    blocks[i].color = dom_blocks[i].dataset.color;
}

console.log(blocks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" data-type="false" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="true"  data-color="green"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="true"  data-color="orange"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="false" data-color="fuchsia"></div>
```

Or for older browsers:

```js
var blocks = [];
var block  = {
    type: null,
    color: null
};

var dom_blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

for (var i = 0, ii = dom_blocks.length; i < ii; i++) {
    blocks[i] = Object.create(block);
    blocks[i].block = dom_blocks[i].getAttribute("data-type");
    blocks[i].color = dom_blocks[i].getAttribute("data-color");
}

console.log(blocks);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="block" data-type="false" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="true"  data-color="green"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="true"  data-color="orange"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="false" data-color="fuchsia"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you T.J! As usual if getting you to answer my questions: There is lots more information I didn't even think about like the dataset browser support. And to answer your question: (BTW, perhaps you meant .type = rather than .block =?) YES that was my problem..! Thank you!

Comment: @caramba: No worries!

Answer (score 1):

Use the cross-browser [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and simplify things by creating the object directly in the push.

There is no need to explicitly call the Object.create()

```js
var blocks = [],
    dom_blocks = document.querySelectorAll('.block');

for(var i= 0, ii = dom_blocks.length; i < ii; i++) {
  blocks.push({
    type: dom_blocks[i].getAttribute('data-type'),
    color: dom_blocks[i].getAttribute('data-color')
  });
}

console.log(blocks);
```

```html
<div class="block" data-type="false" data-color="red"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="true"  data-color="green"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="true"  data-color="orange"></div>
<div class="block" data-type="false" data-color="fuchsia"></div>

<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```